# Mocha, Chai: Assert that Object is included in an Array of Objects

Tags: javascript, testing, mocha.js, chai

Chai has a nice way to assert if an Array includes a certain element

```
expect([1,2,3]).to.include(2);
```

What I would like is something similar, given an Array of Objects:

```
expect([{a:1},{b:2}]).to.include({b:2});
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Did you try it?  The documentation seems to imply that it would work. http://chaijs.com/api/bdd/#include

Comment: Yeah I tried -- those examples only show how to test if a certain key exists, not the actual value (or entire object for that matter)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Take a look at the [Chai Things plugin](http://chaijs.com/plugins/chai-things), that does what you want:

```
[{a:1},{b:2}].should.include.something.that.deep.equals({b:2})
```

Comment: and if you had check [{a:1},{a: 2}].contains(['a']) how would you do that

Comment: @PirateApp, I think it may be like this:
`[{ a: 'cat' }, { a: 'dog' }].should.all.have.property('a')`
https://github.com/chaijs/chai-things#all

Comment: Note that Chai Things plugin's last commit was in 2016.

Answer (score 37):

Here is an alternative and non order dependent approach for collections:

## array

```
expect([1, 2, 3]).to.include.members([3, 2, 1])
```

You can also use this with a `deep` flag for comparison of objects:

## array of objects

```
expect([{ id: 1 }]).to.deep.include.members([{ id: 1 }]);
```

## object

```
expect({foo: 'bar', width: 190, height: 90}).to.include({ height: 90, width: 190 })
```

Answer (score 27):

You can use deep method for the array of objects.

```
expect([{a:1},{b:2}]).to.deep.include({b:2});   //It will pass
```

You can find more examples using deep method here: http://chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_deep

The main point to remember here is about reference types.

Comment: I should have seen this solution before! This worked for me since chai-things seems not supported in Chai v4

Comment: this is a better solution as it doesn't require to use another dependency